# How to pass variable out of page context using phantomjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I have the following function in a phantomjs script:

```
 page.injectJs("jquery.js");
 var message = null;

       page.evaluate(function(message) {
         message = $('mydiv').text() 
         console.log('message inside' + message );
        },message);
          console.log('message is ' + message );
```

inside the function the correct message is logged. outside I get:

```
message is null
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Is "mydiv" an id of div? In that case you should change your jquery selector to:

```
$('#mydiv').text()
```

Comment: Its actually <div class="abc"> text here </div>. does that change anything?

Comment: Try `$($('.abc')[0]).text()`. This is to refer to the first element of those with `class="abc"`. You can refer to elements by $('.class'), $('#id') or $('tagName') - all of the above will correspond a list of 0 or more matching elements.

Comment: Thank you, but so far no success- Bill

Comment: I found the answer in http://www.cameronjtinker.com/post/2011/09/27/Passing-information-to-and-from-webpages-in-PhantomJS.aspx